# How to use git for projects which has shared files

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-for-windows

Our web development team uses shared folders (Windows) to work on projects together.
We never make local copies of project , but always edit the files in-place.
Now I've heard we would be much better off using git  .
Is git a reasonable option is this case? And if so, how can we use it?

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. Please edit the grammar and provide some more details if there is something I am missing other than asking what Git is. From what I understand now, you should definitely be using Git. Read the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) if you need to learn it.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss i mentioned one example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use git, and you should. Git will allow your team members to work on the same files at the same time. Think Google Docs, but much more clever and for programming. There's a really good Udacity lesson on how to use Git/GitHub. It should only take you a few hours, but it'll dramatically improve your collaboration skills.

Since your team has designers, any large files that are not code (like images, videos, etc), you can keep on the shared folder. Make a .gitignore file in your project root directory. You can use this file to specify which files that git will "ignore" when pushing changes. Since your files in the shared drive are already accessible from all your team members, there's no need to redundantly back them up via git.

Check out the documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Also, I have found [this](https://www.gitignore.io/) website to be particularly useful in auto-generating gitignore files.